# To get correct ascending order using sql query

Tags: sql

My sql query is..

```
Select left(Bundle_code,2)
From Item_bundle 
where Item_code='F-4X10AL' and Branch ='KOCHI'
Order by CAST ( Case When ISNUMERIC (left(Bundle_code,2))=1 
                     Then left( Bundle_code,2) 
                     Else -99 End as Int)
```

The result I got was

```
result:
2B
6B
3B
7B
8B
9B
10
11
```

But the order is not correct .Please help me to get a correct order

Comment: use order by after the case

Comment: The order i need is 2B 3B 6B 7B 8B 9B and so on

Comment: is it 10,11 that you want to consider or 10B, 11B?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want Bundle_code as int (1,2..) + 'B' you can write as:

```
Select  SUBSTRING(Bundle_code,0,CHARINDEX('B',Bundle_code,0) + 1) as Bundle_code
From Item_bundle where Item_code='F-4X10AL' and Branch ='KOCHI'
Order by cast(SUBSTRING(Bundle_code,0,CHARINDEX('B',Bundle_code,0)) as int)
```